# 403 Error on AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, users, javascript, routes

I defined the following menu item on my module:

```
function visita_virtual_menu(){
$items = array();
$items['visita_virtual/marker_selected_handler'] = array(
        'title' => t('Marker Selected Handler'),
        'description' => t('Ajax handler for selected markers'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access panoramas'),
        'callback' => 'marker_selected_handler');
return $items;
```

}

And even created an special permission for my module:

```
function visita_virtual_permission(){
return array('access panoramas' => array(
        'title' => t('Configurar Panoramas'),
        'description' => t('Configurar la visita virtual'),
        )
);
```

}

Obviously the access panoramas permission appeared on the People Permissions configuration tab on Drupal. I assigned it for anonymous users, logged users, and administrator users (Just for testing purposes).

Now my javascript function does the following:

```
alert('Callback URL: '+url);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : {
          'marker_latitude' : location.lat,
          'marker_longitude' : location.lng,
        },
        success : function(data){
            alert('Entro a la funcion success');
        },
        error: function(xmlhttp) {
            alert('An error ocurred: '+xmlhttp.status);
        }
    });
```

The `alert('Callback URL: '+url);` line shows the following info:

/drupal/visita_virtual/marker_selected_handler

However I'm always getting 403 access forbidden error. Why?? What I'm doing wrong???

I have been debugging the server's code, and the problem seems to be at this piece of code on menu.inc.

```
function menu_execute_active_handler($path = NULL, $deliver = TRUE) {
// Check if site is offline.
$page_callback_result = _menu_site_is_offline() ? MENU_SITE_OFFLINE : MENU_SITE_ONLINE;

// Allow other modules to change the site status but not the path because that
// would not change the global variable. hook_url_inbound_alter() can be used
// to change the path. Code later will not use the $read_only_path variable.
$read_only_path = !empty($path) ? $path : $_GET['q'];
drupal_alter('menu_site_status', $page_callback_result, $read_only_path);

// Only continue if the site status is not set.
if ($page_callback_result == MENU_SITE_ONLINE) {
if ($router_item = menu_get_item($path)) {
  if ($router_item['access']) {
    if ($router_item['include_file']) {
      require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $router_item['include_file'];
    }
    $page_callback_result = call_user_func_array($router_item['page_callback'],   $router_item['page_arguments']);
  }
  else {
    $page_callback_result = MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
  }
```

The `$path` parameter is getting it's default value. NULL, and then the `$read_only_path` is obtained from the `q` `$_GET` value, for this case the $read_only_path has it's value set on: `visita_virtual/marker_selected_handler` Is that ok?? shouldn't it be `/drupal/visita_virtual/marker_selected_handler`?

At this point `$router_item = menu_get_item($path)` I'm getting a $router_item that has an 'access' value of false. So that's the reason I'm receiving 403. Still I'm lost, I don't know what I'm configuring wrong for the menu...

Comment: are you logged in as admin ?did Amernath ans worked ? are you still having same problem ? or you found solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an *Access denied* is because your menu item doesn't have a `page callback` attribute specified. (You have used `callback` instead). You can check the documentation of `hook_menu()` [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

On the same page, you'd notice that it says - when the `page callback` attribute is omitted for a menu item, the `page callback` of its parent will be taken.

However, when a parent doesn't exist for the menu item in question, it returns an `Access denied`. This happens even before the current user's access to your menu item is resolved; so the `access callback` doesn't really matter. (explains why changing that hasn't helped)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Ajax, but try to add to

```
$items['visita_virtual/marker_selected_handler'] = array(
  // ...
  'access callback' => TRUE,
)
```

Comment: I tried it, however still I'm getting 403 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
'access callback' => 'user_access',
```

In the menu definition (then disable/enable the module)